# How can I reverse the axis in a biplot

Tags: r, plot, axis, pca, biplot

When I plot a PCA and then the corresponding biplot, the axis are not always in the same direction, just like in these pictures:

[image: plot(pc...)]
[image: biplot(princomp...]

These are the functions, I used:

```
(pc <- prcomp(dat5, center=T, retx=T, scale=T)); summary(pc)
plot(pc$x[,1:2], pch=""); text(pc$x[,1:2], cex=.5, labels=(row.names(dat5)), col=as.numeric(dat$ObCl))     
biplot(princomp(dat5, cor=T), cex=.5)
```

How can I change the axis direction of one of those, to make them the same?

Comment: You second plot is pretty clear, but how did you generate the first one.  What is `pc`?

Comment: likely the result of `prcomp`. A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) always helps by the way

Comment: Exactly :) Sorry for beeing too short. This is the prcomp code:

Comment: (pc <- prcomp(dat5, center=T, retx=T, scale=T)); summary(pc)

Comment: Thank you for editing, MrFlick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sign of PCs being arbitrary, you can change it/them by multiplying one or more PCs by -1. Note that this stands only for representation only, depending on what you do, eg if you use `$rotation` you may also need to change the corresponding columns as well. An example with `iris` follows. Hope this helps.

```
p <- prcomp(iris[, -5])
plot(p$x[, 1:2], asp=1, xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2")
```

[image]

```
plot(cbind(p$x[, 1], p$x[, 2]*-1), asp=1, xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2")
```

[image]

Comment: plot(cbind(pc$x[,1], pc$x[,2]*-1), asp=1, xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2");

Comment: text(cbind(pc$x[,1], pc$x[,2]*-1), asp=1, xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2", cex=.5, labels=(row.names(dat5)), col=as.numeric(dat$ObCl))

Comment: # I just don't get rid of the symbols with pch="", since I want to use text instead...

Comment: plot(cbind(p$x[, 1], p$x[, 2]*-1), asp=1, xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2", pch=NA);
text(cbind(p$x[, 1], p$x[, 2]*-1), labels=1:150). Just replace 1:150 by your labels and you can use colors as well.

Comment: Aaah, pch=NA :) Thank you again :)